# Are the Chiss navigators a Dune reference?

Tags: star-wars, dune

In the *Thrawn* series, we learn that in order to navigate the hazards of the Unknown Regions, Chiss ships use special navigators that are Force Sensitive.

> Called Skywalkers in Chi'un

This sounds very similar to another sci-fi universe.  In the Dune universe, navigators are special humans that take a lot of spice and can get a bit of precognition, which allows them to navigate foldspace.

Did Zahn and the Star Wars story team acknowledge this as an intentional node to Dune, or is it a happy coincidence?

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me, I think both series had some pot-shots at each other along the way. There was a line in one of the Dune books that described a person who was fond of cheap imitators as a "three-PO" (because three cheap imitations of popular products in the Dune universe started with "PO").

Comment: My guess would be that there are older references as well. Which one the Star Wars creator(s) had in mind, if any, would require a direct statement by Zahn.

Comment: If the Star Wars story teams took time to acknowledge everything they were lifting from Dune they would still be working on A New Hope.